# Determine for which nonnegative real number $\displaystyle\alpha$ the series converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Determine (with proof) for which **nonnegative real numbers** $\alpha$ the series
$$
\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n^\alpha}-sin\left(\frac{1}{n^\alpha}\right)\right)
$$

---

OK, first I broke the whole thing into two sums:
$$
\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^\alpha}-\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}sin\left(\frac{1}{n^\alpha}\right)
$$
We know the first term is a *p*-series, therefore $\alpha>1$ for it to be convergent. However, I don't know which convergence tests I should use for the second sum.

And **one more general question**, for the sum of two summations (like above) to be convergent, does it require that both of the summations are convergent?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't break it up. The series you start with converges for some $\alpha$ for which neither part alone converges. When $\alpha > 0$, you have $\frac{1}{n^\alpha} \to 0$. How does $\sin x$ look for $x \approx 0$?

Comment: @DanielFischer even though $\displaystyle sinx\to0$ for $x \approx 0$, what does it imply?

Comment: It implies that you can use the Taylor expansion of $\sin$ to get the asymptotic behaviour of the terms of the series. $\sin x = x - \frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{x^5}{5!} - \dotsb$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that breaking into sums is not valid if both series are divergent (which is the case if $\alpha\leqslant 1$.

However, here, we can use a Taylor expansion of sine at $0$ in order to get 
$$\sin(n^{-\alpha})=n^{-\alpha}+\frac{n^{-2\alpha}}2+n^{-2\alpha}\varepsilon_n,$$
with $\lim_{n\to\infty}\varepsilon_n=0$.